# How to implement scroll composite only for an inner composite

Tags: swt, scrolledcomposite

[image]

I am trying to implement a scrolled composite for one of the composite (top composite as shown in the picture). My intention is to add a scroll bar for the upper composite only, because when the window gets resized then save button becomes invisible sometimes.

I have tried with scrolled composite implementation for the upper composite. But when I try to resize it then I am not getting a scroll bar for it even if I have set the minimum size for the scrolledComposite.

Also when I specify `scrolledComposite.setAlwaysShowScrollBars(true)`, I am able to see only the placeholder for the scrollbar which is in disabled mode.

Below is my code snippet.

```java
public void init() {
        setFocus();
        preInit();
        createCaseGroup(this);

        //Here "this" is the parent composite
        Composite childComp = new Composite(this, SWT.None);
        childComp.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, true));
        childComp.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));

        final ScrolledComposite scrolledComposite = new ScrolledComposite(childComp,
                SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.BORDER);

        final Composite Comp = new Composite(scrolledComposite, SWT.NONE);
        Comp.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, true));
        Comp.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));

        scrolledComposite.setContent(Comp);
        scrolledComposite.setExpandHorizontal(true);
        scrolledComposite.setExpandVertical(true);

        // scrolledComposite.setMinSize(Comp.computeSize(400, 400) );
        scrolledComposite.setMinSize(400, 400);
        scrolledComposite.setAlwaysShowScrollBars(true);

        objectComposite = new GUIObjectComposite(Comp, SWT.NONE, true);
        objectComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, false));
        objectComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));
        objectComposite.init();
        objectComposite.isNullSelectionAllowed(false);
        GridData gridData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
        gridData.heightHint = 130;
        gridData.horizontalSpan = 2;
        objectComposite.setLayoutData(gridData);
        GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(1, false);
        layout.marginHeight = 0;
        layout.marginWidth = 0;
        layout.verticalSpacing = 0;
        objectComposite.setLayout(layout);

        // Group for Define interaction(s)
        Group defineInteractionGroup = new Group(childComp, SWT.NONE);
        GridData defineInteractionGridData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
        defineInteractionGridData.horizontalSpan = 2;
        defineInteractionGroup.setLayoutData(defineInteractionGridData);
        GridLayout defineInteractionLayout = new GridLayout(1, true);
        defineInteractionLayout.marginHeight = 0;
        defineInteractionLayout.marginWidth = 0;
        defineInteractionLayout.verticalSpacing = 0;
        defineInteractionGroup.setLayout(defineInteractionLayout);
        defineInteractionGroup
                .setText(ResourceAssistant.getString(InteractionExpandedComposite.class, "defineInteraction")); //$NON-NLS-1$

        // Composite for Define interaction(s)
        Composite interactionComposite = new Composite(defineInteractionGroup, SWT.NONE);
        interactionComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
        GridLayout interactionCompositeLayout = new GridLayout(11, true);
        interactionCompositeLayout.marginHeight = 10;
        interactionCompositeLayout.verticalSpacing = 0;
        interactionComposite.setLayout(interactionCompositeLayout);

        Composite actionsComposite = new Composite(interactionComposite, SWT.NONE);
        GridData actionsCompositeGridData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
        actionsCompositeGridData.horizontalSpan = 2;
        actionsComposite.setLayoutData(actionsCompositeGridData);
        ActionsFormProvider actionsFormProvider = new ActionsFormProvider();
        List<IFormItem> actionFormItems = actionsFormProvider.generateFormItems();
        for (IFormItem actionItem : actionFormItems) {
            actionItem.create(actionsComposite);
        }

        IWorkbenchWindow iWorkbenchWindow = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
        IWorkbenchPartSite activePartSite = iWorkbenchWindow.getActivePage().getActivePart().getSite();
        activePartSite.setSelectionProvider(objectComposite.getViewer());

        ISelectionService selectionService = iWorkbenchWindow.getSelectionService();
        if (selectionService instanceof AbstractSelectionService) {
            AbstractSelectionService abstractSelectionService = (AbstractSelectionService) selectionService;
            abstractSelectionService.setActivePart(null);
            abstractSelectionService.setActivePart(getExpandedView());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just a note that you are using `AbstractSelectionService`. This is an **internal** class and as such should not be used.

Comment: The code you posted is far from compiling standalone. Could you please provide a self-contained snippet that still demonstrates the problem?